# How to import a Gradle project with a different structure in intellij

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea

I was recently working on a Gradle project with a weird project structure, as shown below

```
ProjectRoot
 - lambda
    - src/main/java
    - settings.gradle
    - gradle.build (notice the gradle.build is not in project root )
 - README.md
 - some other files needed for the application
```

When i imported the project to intelliJ, the classes with "src/main/java" are not able to resolve the dependencies properly.

how do i fix this issue?

Please find a sample project at https://github.com/ashipj/gradle-sample

Comment: Is "src/main/java" marked as sources root?

Comment: I did try adding "/lambda/src/main/java" in sourceSets. But that didn't work as well.

Comment: Is it possible to attach sample project example?

Comment: Sorry it took some time. Please find the sample project at https://github.com/ashipj/gradle-sample.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a settings.gradle with these instructions:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
rootProject.name = 'name of your project root'
```

This should be in the same directory of build.gradle

Comment: tried rootProject.name = 'lambda'. But, that didn't fix the issue.

Comment: could you show me your build.gradle? Cause if u specified correctly the rootProject.name, u should be able to compile all your dependencies. I see in my root project folder "folderName [nameInside] path of folder", and in my rootProject,name i have rootProject.name = 'nameInside', and u?

Comment: I have created a sample project at https://github.com/ashipj/gradle-sample.

Comment: in settings.gradle add `pluginManagement {
 repositories {
  gradlePluginPortal()
 }
}` and in build.gradle change implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-jre' to compile 'com.google.guava:guava:27.1-jre'